# Typescript can seem to infer that a key is valid

Tags: typescript, type-inference

Typescript fails to to infer that `extension` is a valid key in `exampleObject`

```
if (extension in exampleObject) {
    const { data } = exampleObject[extension]
}
```

and throws the following error

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type
```

[Playground demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM+AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL+gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBEoITiCGhrBiIBaQADy0gAVpBYDQALygADeihKJQARPFIHgAAwARkF+V5-IFJW4dQYMsFqAkpQUq1QpW+bDIpWkDEEkEFvDlJQAvmb5cLRWKAEzS2XyhVKlVqjVrbUETaOPClBjQVCO60Cq3m0C28UAZidfJdcLdkY9mu1gnYsAsgkEBqNJtDloLkZF4oALHGI67UMrk+rU6VcmROMNc8bTRGLXKLQBucloqk0ZJcWCgbkACi9KLkjRl1MonGYAEpRwA+Z0ChGgCdaqcNLwZcGrOkM5lsjnL+MuynU3mJ6ugC2jw-H9yn9moADak6pe4Auh2uz7YIVBwZoPCbUBEHgPoGGBdgaC+NwzGYdgGGYSB+FgaB1ESWD4D0EQvEFABRI96XcQRBSSbFBXABxUAAcmEAA5SAJEFIIVEZL4yHeY1+HQo5qzIBRXGkPBQCcKCdGGLB9BQBBEGhYRLkQiRoOiEQDA4bEFiYVgOB4IISiAA)

I tried to re-write the access to the object in multiple ways but it would always lead to that same error.
According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65050560/typescript-type-inference-in-an-if-statement-doesnt-work-as-a-variable) this should work after typescript 4.4, I'm on 5.3 and this still doesn't work.

Comment: [Consider this code](https://tsplay.dev/wednaW) - just because a key exists in an object does not mean it will match *the type*. TS uses structural equality anything with *at least* the same keys and values will be assignable to that type. But it can have more. Do you *really* want to accept any arbitrary key? As opposed to keys that belong to the type?

Comment: You can always use `exampleObject[extension as keyof typeof exampleObject]`, but if there's a way to make TS automatically infer this, I don't know how. Probably for the reason that you can add arbitrary keys, as @VLAZ highlighted.

Comment: [^^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78001231/typescript-can-seem-to-infer-that-a-key-is-valid#comment137512041_78001231) So the solution, which I think is  fairly well-covered by previous questions and answers, is to have `func` accept `extension: keyof typeof exampleObject` rather than `extension: string` or, if you have to accept `string`, to use a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) or an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions).

Comment: VLAZ if a given string is a key to an object then it belongs to the type or am I missing something?

Taxel if I blindly cast types than typescript starts to lose it's usefulness

T.J.Crowder extension is a string because the input will not necessarily be a key to the object and will have to be handled another way, but the assertion function seems to be what I'm looking for

Comment: ① Please [edit] to put your example as plaintext in the question itself, not only as a link to another site.  Otherwise it lacks debugging details and might be closed for that reason. ② If a key belongs to an object that doesn't mean it is known to exist on the type the compiler has for the object.  Types can be extended with extra properties... with `interface Foo {a: string}; interface Bar extends Foo {b: number}`,  every `Bar` is a `Foo` with a `b` property.  So if you have a `Foo`, it might well have a `b` property (e.g., because it's a `Bar`) *or any other property*.

Comment: "*if a given string is a key to an object then it belongs to the type or am I missing something*" no, that's what I explained. And demonstrated to you. A key might not be in the type. Here is another demo: https://tsplay.dev/wQjeGN